# Create import file from 2 txt files

Tags: wordpress, powershell

I´m trying to export my Kunena forum posts to import them into our new wp forum server. For this I´ve created 2 files... One which contains the messages in the following format:

```
(`id`, `parent`, `thread`, `catid`, `name`, `userid`, `email`, `subject`, `time`, `ip`, `topic_emoticon`, `locked`, `hold`, `ordering`, `hits`, `moved`, `modified_by`, `modified_time`, `modified_reason`)
```

The other contains the text for the message:

```
(`mesid`, `message`)
```

From the first file I only need the "fields" id, parent, time, userid, subject and hits.
From the second i need the corresponding "field" message

Afterwards it should be formatted like this:

```
(`id`, `message`, `parent`, `time`, `userid`, `subject`, `hits`)
```

Since there are hundreds of posts and the copy & paste thing is really time consuming i thought it would be a lot easier to do this via a script... Preferably by PowerShell...

Hope you guys can help me out...

```
$outputFile = "C:\logFile.txt"
$path = "C:\kunena_messages.txt"
$path2 = "C:\kunena_messages_text.txt"

get-content $path | % {$array = $_ -split ",","0"                 
                     $message = get-content $path2 | %{If($_ -match ($array[0].Trim() -replace "\(","" )){
                                $msgArray = $_ -split ",","0"
                                $msgArray[1] -replace "\)",""}}
                      $newString = $array[0].Trim()+","+$message +","+$array[1].Trim()+","+`
                                        $array[8].Trim()+","+$array[5].Trim()+","+$array[7].Trim()+","+`
                                        $array[14].Trim()+")" 
                      $newString | ac $outputFile

}
```

Comment: How are the messages linked to your users?

Comment: they are linked via the the field userid which includes the id of the user which are configured in another table

Comment: If the answer below has helped or has answered your question could you upvote it or accept it, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this to get the information you require:

```
$outputFile = "C:\logFile.txt"
$path = "C:\test\test.txt"
get-content $path | %{$array = $_ -split ",","0"
                      $message ="This is a message"
                      $newString = "("+$array[0].Trim()+","+$message +","+$array[1].Trim()+","+`
                                        $array[8].Trim()+","+$array[5].Trim()+","+$array[7].Trim()+","+`
                                        $array[14].Trim()+")" 
                      $newString | ac $outputFile
                    }
```

This will give the following output in the given file (`$outputFile`).

```
("`id`,`This is a message`,`parent`,`time`,`userid`,`subject`,`hits`)
("`id2`,`This is a message`,`parent2`,`time`,`userid`,`subject`,`hits`)
("`id3`,`This is a message`,`parent2`,`time`,`userid`,`subject`,`hits`)
```

As you can see I have picked out all the parts you required apart from the message; as I'm not sure how you are linking the two. All you will need to do is use a similar method to get the correct message and put it into the variable `$message`.

---

Going on the assumption that your ID and MesID are the same you can use something like this for the `$message` varible:

```
$path2 = "C:\Messages\test.txt"          
$message = get-content $path2 | %{ $msgArray = $_ -split ",","0" -replace "\)",""
                                   $msgArray = $msgArray -replace "\(",""
                                   $m = $array[0].Trim() -replace "`"","" 
                                   If($msgArray[0].Trim() -eq $m){$msgArray[1]}
                                  }
```

`$path2` being the path to your message file.

---

So all together it should look like this:

```
$outputFile = "C:\logFile.txt"
$path = "C:\kunena_messages.txt"
$path2 = "C:\kunena_messages_text.txt"

get-content $path | %{$array = $_ -split ",","0"
                      $array = $array -replace "\(","" `
                                      -replace "\)","" `
                                      -replace "`"",""
                      $message = get-content $path2 | %{ $msgArray = $_ -split ",","0" -replace "\)",""
                                                         $msgArray = $msgArray -replace "\(",""
                                                         $m = $array[0].Trim() -replace "`"","" 
                                                         If($msgArray[0].Trim() -eq $m){$msgArray[1]}
                                                        }
                      $newString = "("+$array[0].Trim()+","+$message +","+$array[1].Trim()+","+`
                                        $array[8].Trim()+","+$array[5].Trim()+","+$array[7].Trim()+","+`
                                        $array[14].Trim()+")" 
                      $newString | ac $outputFile
                    }
```

Comment: Yes... That´s what I´m trying to do but only that I´m trying to use the id for mesid since this is the reference for the post

Comment: I´ll post the new script to the original post

Comment: Ok, just to be clear it's the `ID` in the first file that is the same as the `mesid` in the second file?

Comment: Yes... The ID in the first file is the same as the mesid in the second... The first part with the static $message variable is working... But when I try to fill the variable at runtime I´m getting BadOperatorArgument error

Comment: I see your problem it's the `$array[0]` variable, It has quotes with in it. I have changed my answer to filter these out with in the `IF` loop.

Comment: Hi Richard, if I´m using the code as you´ve changed it in your answer all the code after the first -replace is used as "replace parameter"... and if i´m deleting one quote from "`"","" after the first -replace so that it looks like "`","" I´m getting an UnexpectedToken error

Comment: ok... i´m getting closer... but to compare only one string i have to use the first paranthese to use it for filtering the exact message entry and not all the messages containing e.g. 26 in the message id

Comment: I´ve changed the script in my question to the current one

Comment: @MircoLueneburg I have changed my answer to use the equal to operator to avoid incorrect message selection when using the `-match` operator and this should all so get around that UnexpectedToken error.